# FInd all files that contains both the string1 and string2

Tags: shell, grep

The following script finds and prints the names of all those files that contains either string1 or string2.

However I could not figure out how to make change into this code so that it prints only those files that contains both string1 and string2. Kindly suggest the required change

```
   number=0
   for file in `find -name "*.txt"`
   do
       if [ "`grep "string2\|string1" $file`" != "" ]   // change has to be done here
       then

      echo "`basename $file`"
      number=$((number + 1))
       fi
   done
   echo "$number"
```

Comment: did you want only the filename which contains that specific string?

Answer (score 2):

Using grep and cut:

```
grep -H string1 input | grep -E '[^:]*:.*string2' | cut -d: -f1
```

You can use this with the `find` command:

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec grep -H string1 {} \; | grep -E '[^:]*:.*string2'
```

And if the patterns are not necessarily on the same line:

```
find -name '*.txt' -exec grep -l string1 {} \; | \
            xargs -n 1 -I{} grep -l string2 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution can handle files with spaces in their names:

```
number=0
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for file in `find -name "*.txt"`
do
  if grep -l "string1" "$file" >/dev/null; then
    if grep -l "string2" "$file" >/dev/null; then
       basename "$file"
      number=$((number + 1))
    fi
  fi
done
echo $number
IFS=$oldIFS
```